# Running Tensorflow in OSX

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, macos-mojave

I wrote simple MNIST tensorflow code...

Code executes very well when I run the code with PyCharm.
But actually, I wanted to run this script in terminal using `python ./mnist.py` command, so when I run the code in terminal, I get the following error.

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH $ORIGIN/../../_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_C_Upywrap_Utensorflow_Uinternal.so___Utensorflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./model_load.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

People said this is related to OSX. There is a warning about `LC_RPATH`.
 Now I want to know whether the error occurs due to `ImportError` or `LC_RPATH` warning

and if `ImportError` and warning is a separate issue here.

How can I solve this problem??
I'm using `osx Mojave`, `pyhton2.7` and `tensorflow 1.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Error and warning was independent.
Mac OS can run tensorflow in terminal whether the warning occurs or not.
The main problem was python couldn't recognize google.protobuf module even if it was installed...

- First check protobuf module and google module was already installed.
  `pip install google` and `pip install protobuf`
- If you got same error after typing both command, it means module is installed but python couldn't find it. So we need to modify module so that python can recognize it.

Move to directory where python package is installed.
In my case `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

In this directory find google directory and check what files are inside.
In my case, only `protobuf` was exist.
This was the reason why python couldn't find the google.protobuf module.
We need to add `__init__.py` file so that python can find module in directory.
So I add empty `__init__.py` file in `google` folder and I could solve the problem.
I hope someone who experience problems like me can solve it with above method.